# Using Rails ActionView/Controller completely outside rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I learnt a bit of basic Rails and one of the attempts I'm making now is to use ActionController and ActionView completely outside of Rails (in a non rails app).

So far what I have is the following example after installing actionpack-4.0.2

```
require 'action_view'
require 'action_controller'

class SimpleController < AbstractController::Base
 include AbstractController::Rendering
 include AbstractController::Layouts
 include AbstractController::Helpers
 include AbstractController::Translation
 include AbstractController::AssetPaths
 include ActionController::UrlFor
 include ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor

 # All the .html.erb files are placed in the folder Views
 self.view_paths = "Views"

 def say_hello
   render_to_string template: "Hello"
 end

 def create_person
   render_to_string template: "Form"
 end

end

c = SimpleController.new
puts c.say_hello
puts c.create_person
```

Hello.html.erb (To be placed in the Views folder)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <%= highlight( 'This is Hello world', 'Hello world') %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Form.html.erb (To be placed in the Views folder)

```
<html>
<body>
<%= form_for( :person, :url => { :action => 'create' } ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>
<% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the output of the above program

```
   <html>
      <body>
        <p>
              This is <mark>Hello world</mark>
            </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/url
    _helper.rb:38:in `url_for': arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please
     require routes or provide your own implementation (ActionView::Template::Error)

            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:729:in `block in html_options_for_form'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:725:in `tap'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:725:in `html_options_for_form'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:67:in `form_tag'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/helpers/form_helper.rb:438:in `form_for'
            from ./Views/Form.html.erb:4:in `_____etho
    ds__uby_html___rototype__iews__orm_html_erb__678800263_20873052'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
    support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/template.rb:141:in `render'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
    support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
    support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_
    support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_vie
    w/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_c
    ontroller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_c
    ontroller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
            from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_c
    ontroller/rendering.rb:113:in `render_to_string'
            from sample.rb:21:in `edit_person'
            from sample.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

The say_hello method works fine with out any issues and I can use most of the ActiveView ViewHelpers in the erb files (Hello.html.erb above uses one such highlight method). So this is a way with which I can generate static html pages by using power of ActionView.

But I'm not able to get the edit_person work as it uses form_for helper and this needs custom url_for implementation or rails standard routes.rb implementation (as prompted in the error message). I would like to get this working with routes.rb approach but I get the impression that I need Rails::Application object and some url_helpers etc (so far I couldn't get it working). Is there a way to do this?

Then later I would like integrate this solution with Webrick to process the requests from browser (when the user creates a person).

Please note this is a attempt to learn some details of Rails and not meant as a solution to any problem that you cannot do with using standard rails framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just create an API to access with your static site? It seems highly insecure to try and extend Rails' native functionality

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean an API to serve static webpages? That I can already do with Webrick. What I'm now interested is to learn how to serve simple dynamic pages by only using ActionPack and Rack (i.e, with out whole of rails). And I thought one of key aspects of Rails is that it is a very well modularized framework which users can try separately and extend themselves.

Comment: While it is claimed that you may use action_pack and action_view outside of rails apps I have yet to find a good example. Your post was the first one that I came across in a search. I would ask you if you find a solution to this then please write up your own answer so the rest of us can benefit. As a side note: AbstractController::Layouts is not correct. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/actionview/lib/action_view.rb  It is now ActionView::Layouts

Comment: As your code is now I just comment out include AbstractController::Layouts and it runs without errors however doing inspects of p render_to_string template: "Hello" and p render_to_string template: "Form" both give me nil in the output.

Comment: A clue to the error we're getting may be found here as we'll have to implement our own routing. And try commenting out include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers first because we aren't using it for obvious reasons. http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionController/UrlFor

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but just for some related code.
To simplify things a bit and I know it still errors but you get some data back in the errors.
I'll show a portion of it after the code.

```
require 'action_controller'

class SimpleController < ActionController::Base

  def say_hello
    p render_to_string template: "Hello"
  end

  def create_person
    p render_to_string template: "Form"
  end
end

c = SimpleController.new
puts c.say_hello
puts c.create_person
```

Skipping the views handler for now.

```
OUT:
> ruby sample.rb
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-   4.1.8/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find': Missing template /Hello with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in: (ActionView::MissingTemplate)
```

The top should be good enough as it just trees up to that anyway.

Now a run with the class views.

We get similar results:
    OUT:

> ruby sample.rb
>       "\n  \n
>
> \n      This is Hello world\n
>
> \n    \n"

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
  This is <mark>Hello world</mark>
</p>
</body>
</html>

.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.1.8/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:38:in `url_for': arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5 introduced the  `ActionController::Renderer` that makes it a bit more convenient to use the Rails template system outside of Rails.

Example:

```
 renderer = ApplicationController.renderer
 content  = renderer.render template: 'ruby_template'
```

(from [the Tests](https://github.com/brainopia/rails/blob/action_view_render/actionpack/test/controller/renderer_test.rb))

It's somewhat useful because plain ERB is severely limited. I'm using it in a generator where life without partials would be inconvenient.